# Why does optimization change the result of double to unsigned int conversion?

Tags: double, unsigned

Given this code: (https://godbolt.org/z/qGneEne7x)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main ()
{
    double d[2] = { 161785254.0, -215713672.0 };
    int i[4];
    unsigned u[4];

    __m128d vd = _mm_loadu_pd(d);
    __m128i vi = _mm_cvtpd_epi32(vd);
    _mm_storeu_si128((void *)i, vi);
    _mm_storeu_si128((void *)u, vi);

    printf("Doubles to convert            : %.1f %.1f\n", d[0], d[1]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("SIMD double to signed int     : %i   %i\n", i[0], i[1]);
    printf("SIMD double stored to unsigned: %u   %u\n", u[0], u[1]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Scalar double to signed int   : %i   %i\n", (int)d[0], (int)d[1]);
    printf("Scalar double to unsigned     : %u   %u\n", (unsigned)d[0], (unsigned)d[1]);
}
```

Why does optimization change the result of the double to unsigned conversion in scalar code?

This is what it prints out with -O0:

```
Doubles to convert            : 161785254.0 -215713672.0

SIMD double to signed int     : 161785254   -215713672
SIMD double stored to unsigned: 161785254   4079253624

Scalar double to signed int   : 161785254   -215713672
Scalar double to unsigned     : 161785254   4079253624
```

Everything is as expected.

Turn on -O1 and scalar to unsigned becomes zero:

```
Scalar double to unsigned     : 161785254   0
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some platforms, processing `(unsigned)d` in a manner that would yield the same result as `(unsigned)(int)d` in all cases where the latter was defined, may be more expensive than processing it in a manner that might yield different results for some such conversions.  Further, for some tasks, having such computations trap when `d` is outside the range of `unsigned` may be more useful than having them yield a meaningless value.  Rather than try to anticipate all of the situations where alternative behaviors might be more useful than `(unsigned)(int)d`, the Standard simply waives jurisdiction over any situations other than those where a simple numeric conversion would yield a result within range of `unsigned int`.